# Changing the branch of the yaml file in an Azure Devops Release Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have an existing Azure Devops pipeline and I would like to change the branch that contains the yaml file. The pipeline has a lot of variables, so I would prefer to not have to create a new one from scratch. When editing the pipeline, I see that I can change the location of the yaml file within the branch. And I also see the dropdown that can be used to switch branches. But I don't see a way to save that new branch configuration.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: You should be able to just check in the same yaml file to your other branch to the same path and the build pipeline will use it.

Comment: @AnthonyKlotz, In my case I am using [multi-repo triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#triggers) and would like to use the yml file from a specific branch. However, the corresponding pipeline in ADO does not let me save the selected branch.

Answer (score 1):

1.If those variables are defined in xx.yml file, to reuse those variables in another branch(Call it **Y** branch) that doesn't contain the `xx.yaml` file, you only need to check in that file to **Y** branch like **Anthony** suggests above. Then the pipeline will locate that file(if it matches `Yaml File path`), and you can choose to run the pipeline with configuration from the branch you want.

In addition: After that, don't forget to modify the [triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers) cause you're now in another branch.

2.And if you already have one `xx.yml` file in **Y** branch, you only need to copy the content of [variables:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-pipeline) part from current yaml file to yaml file in **Y** branch and commit the change.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi Lance! Thanks for the feedback. So are you saying that when I run the pipeline on the branch Y, the branch Y version of the yaml file will automatically be used? If so, then I never had a problem in the first place.

Comment: Yes if you're running a pipeline with yaml format, and you can confirm it easily by define a test variable with different value in yml file. And note if you're running a classic UI pipeline, it won't use the yaml file though it exists. Classic and YAML are two different directions. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/pipelines-get-started?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).